# Is there any reference or information for creating an input method for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, input-method-kit

Any information is welcome.

I know nothing about the APIs for input methods in OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [Input Method Kit Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/InputMethodKitFrameworkRef/_index.html) and the [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NumberInput_IMKit_Sample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007466).

Comment: Did you read the "about" page: "This sample includes five stages. You begin with a simple do nothing version and move to a full version." What stage are you on?

Comment: [link](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=698183#c12) helps, Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Maadiah move the product `.app` into `/Library/Input Methods/`. You can then select that input method from System Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [Input Method Kit framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/InputMethodKitFrameworkRef/).

Apple provides the [`NumberInput` project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/NumberInput_IMKit_Sample/Introduction/Intro.html) as an InputMethodKit code sample.

> This sample includes five stages. You begin with a simple do nothing version and move to a full version.

I found their provided sample code rather hard to follow, as each "step" in the project is distributed in its own folder. I've uploaded each step as a separate commit in a git project here:

https://github.com/pkamb/NumberInput_IMKit_Sample